# iOS : Uploading In Memory Audio Data to RTSP Server

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation, rtsp

In my app I have to record sound from default mic of device and send it to RTSP server for streaming further.

**My Recorder State Structure is:**

```
typedef struct AQRecorderState {
    AudioStreamBasicDescription  mDataFormat;                   // 2
    AudioQueueRef                mQueue;                        // 3
    AudioQueueBufferRef          mBuffers[kNumberRecordBuffers];// 4
    AudioFileID                  mAudioFile;                    // 5
    UInt32                       bufferByteSize;                // 6
    SInt64                       mCurrentPacket;                // 7
    bool                         mIsRunning;                    // 8
}AQRecorderState;
```

**My Setting Parameters for recording is:**

```
    ars.mDataFormat.mSampleRate     = 44100;
    ars.mDataFormat.mChannelsPerFrame   = 1;
    ars.mDataFormat.mFramesPerPacket    = 1;
    ars.mDataFormat.mBitsPerChannel     = 16;
    ars.mDataFormat.mBytesPerFrame      = ars.mDataFormat.mChannelsPerFrame * sizeof (SInt16); // BYTES_PER_FRAME;
    ars.mDataFormat.mBytesPerPacket     = ars.mDataFormat.mChannelsPerFrame * sizeof (SInt16); // BYTES_PER_PACKET;

    /*----------------- FORMAT -------------------*/
    ars.mDataFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    ars.mDataFormat.mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsBigEndian | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked;

    // derive the buffer size
    DeriveBufferSize(ars.mQueue, ars.mDataFormat, kBufferSeconds, &ars.bufferByteSize);

    // create the queue
    AudioQueueNewInput(&ars.mDataFormat,
                       AQInputCallback,
                       (__bridge void *)(self),
                       NULL,
                       kCFRunLoopCommonModes,
                       0,
                       &ars.mQueue);

// set the magic cookie for the queue
    setMagicCookieForFile(ars.mQueue, ars.mAudioFile);

    // allocate and enque the recording buffers
    for (int i=0; i<kNumberRecordBuffers; i++){
        AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(ars.mQueue, ars.bufferByteSize, &ars.mBuffers[i]);
        AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(ars.mQueue, ars.mBuffers[i], 0, NULL);
    }

    // set current packet index and run state
    ars.mCurrentPacket = 0;
    ars.mIsRunning = true;

    // start the recording
    AudioQueueStart(ars.mQueue, NULL);
```

**And My Input Callback Looks Like:**

```
static void AQInputCallback(void *aqRecorderState,
            AudioQueueRef                        inQ,
            AudioQueueBufferRef                  inBuffer,
            const AudioTimeStamp                 *timestamp,
            unsigned long                        inNumPackets,
            const AudioStreamPacketDescription   *mDataFormat)
{

    NSLog(@"........Callback called");
    AppDelegate *THIS=(__bridge AppDelegate *)aqRecorderState;
    AQRecorderState *pArs = &(THIS->ars);

    if (inNumPackets > 0) {
        write_audio_frame(THIS->oc, THIS->audio_st);
        // Stream audio frame
        uint8_t *data;

        AVCodecContext *codec;
        AVPacket packet;
        uint32_t size = inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize;

        long sample_time_ms = (long)(timestamp->mSampleTime * 1000 / SAMPLE_RATE);

        codec = THIS->audio_st->codec;

        data = av_malloc(size*100);
        if (!data) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't allocate data for audio_frame\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        NSLog(@"Size 1 : %d",size);

        av_init_packet(&packet);
        packet.size = avcodec_encode_audio(codec, data, size, inBuffer->mAudioData);

        NSLog(@"Size 2: %d",packet.size);

        packet.data = data;
        packet.pts = sample_time_ms;
        packet.dts = sample_time_ms;
        packet.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
        packet.duration = (size * 8 * 1024 * 1000000)/BITS_PER_CHANNEL;
        packet.stream_index = THIS->audio_st->index; //audio_st->index

        pArs->mCurrentPacket += inNumPackets;  // advance packet index pointer

        if (av_interleaved_write_frame(THIS->oc, &packet) != 0) {
            exit(1);
        }

        pArs->mCurrentPacket += inNumPackets;  // advance packet index pointer

        av_free(data);
    }

}
```

I am getting data in my input callback, and if write it to file and then play it then it is working good, but my stuff is to not save in file but sending that data directly to RTSP server.

**NOTE :** I am using `av_interleaved_write_frame()` for writing frames to server, I think the problem is in converting `AVPacket` in my input callback and thats why I am getting "OUt of order" packets at server side.

I have searched everywhere over internet but can't find anything working. Please help if anyone has some idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

are you using tcp or udp, I would think out of order packets and dropped packets would be an issue for udp, ffmpeg can do packet re-ordering when necessary.